# studio.sh command not found - Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio

I am trying to get Android Studio running. I have installed jdk and jre

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

I have set up my .bashrc and `/etc/environment` file to

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

but still nothing.

`$JAVA_HOME` returns correct value and so do `java -version` and whereis javac

What am I missing?

Comment: Open a console and cd into "{installation home}/bin" and type: `./studio.sh`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Following step worked for me

1. cd to **YOUR_DIR_WHERE_ANDROID_STUDIO_TILL_BIN_FOLDER**
2. then type command **sh studio.sh** or **./studio.sh**

Comment: I first uninstalled my already existing older version of AS, and then extracted the new version of AS.

I tried using ./studio.sh on android_studio_bin_folder, but getting command not found error

Answer (score 5):

Try using **sh ./studio.sh** instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Typing command `sh studio.sh` in the directory `android-studio/bin`, I solved this issue, so you ought to try this one instead as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me 
-> Go to directory that has android studio bin.

-> Instead of using studio.sh use the command **sh studio.sh**[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed android studio using jetbrains Toolbox then there is the path location

```
/home/username/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7678000/bin/
```